# Use string functions to edit math formula

Tags: regex, xslt

input xml:

```
<sheet-data>
  <variable name='A' formula='(varOne*1000/varTwo-varThree)/varFour'/>
  <variable name='B' formula='(-varOne)/varTwo'/>
  <variable name='C' formula='1000*varOne/(varTwo+varThree)'/>
</sheet-data>
```

I need to show the value-of each formula but add '.value' after each 'var' in the formulas. so that the output xml looks like so:

```
(varOne.value*1000/varTwo.value-varThree.value)/varFour.value
(-varOne.value)/varTwo.value
1000*varOne.value/(varTwo.value+varThree.value)
```

The following code is the xslt code. I understand why this isnt working but I'm not sure how to fix it... On a side note, there are no page breaks in the output with this current xslt code. Anyone have advice on the easiest way to achieve this? The output method is ="text".

```
<xsl:template match='sheet-data'>
  <xsl:for-each select='./*'>
    <xsl:value-of select='replace("@formula", "[A-z]+", ".value")'/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Which XSLT version and engine are you using?

Comment: Are the names of the variables always going to be like varOne, varTwo, varThree or could it be anything?

Comment: @Sebastien I'm using xslt v 2.0 and Saxon HE edition V9.9.1.5. The variable names could be anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
<xsl:template match="/sheet-data">
    <xsl:for-each select="variable">
        <xsl:value-of select="replace(@formula, '(var[A-z]+)([^A-z]|$)', '$1.value$2')"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

---

This assumes all your vars start with the string `"var"`. If this assumption is incorrect, you could use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace(@formula, '([A-z]+)', '$1.value')"/>
```

instead. However, this assumes that any substring of consecutive alpha characters is a "var".